# Yield Google Tag Manager snippet in <head> in EmberJS

Tags: ember.js, google-tag-manager

I have several Ember projects under the same repo and would like to be able to reuse the GTM snippet across all of their `.html` files.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    {{content-for "head"}}

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/employer-vendor.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/employer.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Should I use `ember-cli-meta-tags`, `ember-cli-inline-content` or similar? In order to have the snippet reusable, it will have to be stored not in `ember-cli-build.js`, since that's within a specific project, but in a shared folder across the board.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great use case for [writing an Ember Addon](https://cli.emberjs.com/release/writing-addons/).

Ember Addon allow you to customize the build pipeline. They provide some hooks to do so. These hooks must be implemented in `index.js` file of the addon. The [syntax of that file](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-addon-output/blob/master/index.js) is a little bit uncommon these days. It's very old and hasn't be modernized yet. There is an ongoing initiative to replace it with a [new format](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/507) but that's not stable yet.

The hook you are looking for is [`contentFor`](https://ember-cli.com/api/classes/Addon.html#method_contentFor). It allows you to inject content into the `{{content-for}}` placeholders in `app/index.html` (and `tests/index.html`). The hook gets the type as the first argument, which maps to the first argument for `{{content-for}}`. The second and third argument gives you access to the configuration and the existing content but both is not needed for your use case. You should return the HTML, which should be injected at this hook, from it.

Using the hook for your use case might look like this:

```js
// index.js

'use strict';

module.exports = {
  name: require('./package').name,

  contentFor(type) {
    if (type === "head") {
      return "a string with Google Tag Manager snippet";
    }
  }
};
```

You can implement that addon as [in-repo addon](https://cli.emberjs.com/release/writing-addons/in-repo-addons/) and later extract it into a standalone package for reusing across multiple apps.